# Is there a way to specifically filter out buses with certain name from GTFS?

Tags: r, arcgis, gtfs, gtfstools

I am dealing with some tricky GTFS from Belgian public transport operator De Lijn, which somehow added **belbus** (demand-response buses) as a bus route that comes every hour on their GTFS, making some poorly served countryside misleadingly appear as a highly accessible area with excellent public transport connection.

In routes.txt, they are listed as this:

| route_id | agency_id | route_short_name | route_long_name | route_desc | route_type | route_url | route_color | route_text_color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61135 | 1 | 460 | Belbus Vlaamse Ardennen | Belbus Vlaamse Ardennen/Belbus Vlaamse Ardennen | 3 |  | FFFFFF | 000099 |

I really want to know how I can filter any routes with "**Belbus**" in their route_desc or route_long_name.

At first I tried to just find them on Excel, delete them, and save it into routes.txt, but of course it didn't work when I calculated stop-level frequency on ArcGIS, since I suppose it just looks at stop_times.txt and does not check if the data in Routes.txt went missing.

I also used [gtfstools](https://ipeagit.github.io/gtfstools/reference/filter_by_route_type.html) to try to filter it by route_type, but it was either take all buses out or not unfortunately.

Comment: Assuming you load the txt into a dataframe called `df`, then with `tidyverse` try:
`df |> filter(grepl(pattern = "Belbus", x = paste(route_long_name, route_desc)) == FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{gtfstools}` maintainer here.

What I'd do:

```r
library(gtfstools)

path <- "path_to_gtfs.zip"

gtfs <- read_gtfs(path)

# select route ids whose route_long_name includes "Belbus"
selected_routes <- gtfs$routes[grepl("Belbus", route_long_name)]$route_id

# filter them out of the gtfs object
filtered_gtfs <- filter_by_route_id(gtfs, selected_routes, keep = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you filter rows using the `str_detect` function from the `stringr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_filtered <- df %>% filter(str_detect(route_long_name, "Belbus") == TRUE)
```